# C# How to set or copy a new object to a global variable which references a parameter via constructor

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference

Say I have these Classes and variables

```
public class Human {
    public string name;
}

public class Home {
    public Human m_oHuman = null;

    public Home(ref Human p_oHuman) { //note the ref
        m_oHuman = p_oHuman;
    }

    //p_oNewHuman takes over the home
    public void TakeOver(Human p_oNewHuman) { //don't need ref, just need copy
        m_oHuman = p_oNewHuman; //Won't work as intended.
    }
}

//Run this code
public Human homeOwner = new Human { name = "Sally" };
public Home home = new Home(ref homeOwner)
public Human homeStealer = new Human { name = "Daisy" };
home.TakeOver(homeStealer);
```

What I'm trying to do is pass `homeOwner` by reference and save that reference in the global variable `m_oHuman` then later I want to try make `homeOwner` "point" to `homeStealer` or at least a copy of `homeStealer` since it's not passed by ref. But doing it the way I've coded seems to make `m_oHuman` lose the initial reference, and so `homeOwner` is still "Sally" when I want it to point to `p_oNewHuman`.

What I'm thinking I must do, instead of `m_oHuman  = p_oNewHuman;`, is go through and copy all the variables from `p_oNewHuman` to `m_oHuman`.

But with the code I'm really working with, there are many members and classes that I'm trying to make work like the code above and I feel this could become cumbersome having to manually copy object variables. So I'm wondering if there was a better or easier way to achieve this goal.

Comment: There are no "global variables" in C#. `TakeOver` just replaces the reference, stored in `m_oHuman` field, to the new one, passed as `TakeOver` method parameter. Also, you're misunderstanding, how `ref` keyword works.

Comment: You would need `m_oHuman` to be a `ref` also but that's not allowed. Not just "not allowed in C#" but also "not allowed by the CLR".